# Remove index.php from url and sub folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a little problem, I have searched and tried so much to the point I don't now what to do.

My url is: https://mypage/xxxx/ but i need to go in to https://mypage/xxxx/public/ to see the page.

In xxxx I have one `.htaccess` that is empty.

When I go to my page https://mypage/xxxx/ I can see all the folders.

When I type https://mypage/xxxx/public I can see the page.

I just want to go to https://mypage/xxxx/ to see my page.

In my public folder, I have this `.htaccess` with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I don't now what to do.

**UPDATE**: this is my structure and my xxxx is a Laravel page.

```
- public_html (main root)
--- xxxx
------- App
------- bootstrap
------- config
------- public
------- resources
------- routes
--- subfolder 2 
--- subfolder 3
```

And I need to go to public_html/xxxx/public to see my page, but I should just go to public_html/xxxx for view the page.

There is something wrong with the `.htaccess`.

Comment: Can you configure the server so that `public/` is the root of the website?

Comment: no, public_html is the main root of the webhotell, and my page is under folder /xxxxxx, and when i go to my folder public_html/xxxxxx i get page not found, 

when i type public_html/xxxxxx/index.php and public_html/xxxxxx/public i can see the page. but i only whant to type public_html/xxxxxx/ and see the page

Comment: "when i type public_html/xxxxxx/index.php and public_html/xxxxxx/public i can see the page" - What's `/xxxxxx`? You don't appear to have mentioned this in your question?

Comment: _Side note:_ Tbh, it would be better if you found some hosting that let's you configure it to fit your applications structure instead of adapting your application to their arbitrary file structure. After all, they are there to serve you, not the other way around.

Comment: Putting the files in the root directory instead of `public` may be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the **.htaccess** file inside your folder

public_html/xxxx/

add this:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)?$ public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: i still see the Index of /xxxx, but if i add xxxx/index.php i see the page, why is the index.php there.

Comment: in title you want to remove index, in text you want to load "public" folder. For now you have the second one. Yes?

Comment: I find this one: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess/ And this one works.

Comment: it fucked up my admin page, so i remove it, i back at square one.

Comment: Based on public_html structure I could see that you have more than one web app on this host. So I recommended to only redirecting XXXX folder to XXXX/public ... for the index.php issue you need to edit the root **.htaccess**

Comment: do you have an example, im not so god in htaccess

Comment: is there in your **public_html/.htaccess** something about **index.php** ? copy the line here

Comment: there is nothing about index.php in that one.